# Paperclip failing to upload on specific scaffold, yet works on others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I know there are tons of questions about paperclip, but I failed to find the answer to my problem.

I know its prob just something simple, but I I'm running out of hair to pull out.

I have paperclip working on other parts of my project, they work with no problem, however, a certain scaffold fails to upload, all the attributes to the uploaded file are nil.

Here are the relevant information.

Model:

```
  has_attached_file :foo,
                    :styles => { :thumb => "140x140>" },
                    :url  => "/data/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/data/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

View:

```
<% form_for(@bar, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    ----------
    <li><%= f.label :top %>
    <%= f.file_field :foo %></li>
    ----------
    <ul><%= f.submit "Save" %></ul>
<% end %>
```

Also, comparing the logs to the parts that work, the :foo attribute seems to be passing different values than in the ones that work.

In the logs, when the paperclip function works, it looks like this

```
"image"=>#<File:/var/folders/M5/M5HEb+WhFxmqNDGH5s-pNE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20100512-1302-5e2e6e-0>
```

when it does not, it seems to pass the file name directly

```
"foo"=>"foo_image.png"
```

I am developing locally on MacOSX using local rails and ruby libs.

Comment: I'm sure it's something a but silly... but did you double checked your multipart flag? Maybe you've some unexcepcted typo... It's not the first time I spent 3 hours testing and debugging because I wrote `:multitarp => true` :)

Comment: Also, check that @bar is the correct variable name and it has the correct type.

Comment: I got it working. I haven't actually narrowed it down just yet since I have gotten really busy. will share the findings as soon as I get it sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still haven't narrowed it down, but just to let people know, the problems went away after erasing all the views and regenerating them from scratch, meaning it was a view issue.

Will follow up.